# The SDK platform-tools version (24.0.1) is too old to check APIs compiled with API 25; please update

Tags: android, sdk, platform-tools

I am getting this error but I have already downloaded the missing components for the API 25 and changed the gradle file to the code bellow. I already Sync everything and it gave me 0 errors but I still get this message bellow the package name on each file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'foodlebeeapp.com.foodlebeeapp'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

}


dependencies {

    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
    compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.4@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile project(':volley')
    compile project(':payUMoneysdk')
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:8.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The full report is:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to update your SDK platform tools.

1 - Launch SDK Manager 
2 - Go to SDK Tools or Launch Standalone SDK Manager
3 - You will see "Update available" ahead of SDK platform tools & SDK tools
4 - Select these components to update

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You have to download/Update the api 25.

**build.gradle file**

```
minSdkVersion = 19
targetSdkVersion = 25
compileSdkVersion = 25
buildToolsVersion = "25"
supportLibraryVersion = "25.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the build tools by going to SDK Manager and find the build tools there. Update them.

If still exists go to Help-> update and check for updates and update to the latest version.

Restart android studio and everything should be set fine